# Ruby on Rails - {{model}} appearing in some inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In some of my form input buttons, the value of some buttons is for example:
Create {{model}}
Why is Ruby on Rails displaying {{model}}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will most likely come from your translations. If in your localisation-file (`config/locales/en.yml` for example) you write something like

```
posts:
  create: Create {{model}}
```

you should call the translation like this:

```
I18n.t('posts.create', :model => 'Post')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to point it: the {{model}} is the old notation. You can use the updated version %{model} in your translation file

Comment: Thanks, adding worked: 

en:
  formtastic:
    yes: 'Yes'
    no: 'No'
    create: 'Create'
    save: 'Save'
    submit: 'Submit'
    required: 'Required'